# Replace a character specific number of times in String Java

Tags: java, string, replace

I want to have a string with matched number of parentheses. So, I count the number of open and close parentheses. Then, I want to replace the extra ones with empty char but actually I'm not able to use replace method in java since it does not accept any limitations in numbers unless you just want the first one. Any ideas?

For example: ((A) -> (A) or (A)) -> (A)

Here is a code I have but currently using replace() method, replaces all the open or close parentheses not specific number of times.

```
int count1 = str.length() - str.replace("(", "").length();
int count2 = str.length() - str.replace(")", "").length();

  if (count1 == count2)
            return str;
        else if (count1 > count2){
                str = str.replace("(", "");
            return str;
        }
        else if (count2 > count1){
                str = str.replace(")", "");
            return str;
        }
```

Comment: You don't have any idea about it?

Comment: Show us what parts of your code you are struggling with.

Comment: Please show your existing code, explain what doesn't work. Show some input / expected output.

Comment: I added an example and my current code.

Answer (score 0):

Would advise using a pair of loops instead of method's like replace to fix the parenthesis as order pmatters. Consider a string such as `"A)("`, though it has the correct number of parenthesis it is still invalid.

```
String  fixParen(String str) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
        int openCount = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<sb.length();i++){
            switch(sb.charAt(i)){
                case '(': ++openCount; break;
                case ')': if(openCount==0){
                    sb.replace(i, i+1, "");
                    continue;
                }else{
                    --openCount;
                }
            }
        }
        int closedCount =0;
        for(int i=sb.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
            switch(sb.charAt(i)){
                case ')': ++closedCount; break;
                case '(': if(closedCount==0){
                    sb.replace(i,i+1,"" );
                    continue;
                }else{
                    --closedCount;
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```